# Positioning a div below another

Tags: css, html, web

I have a div that contains an image with a width of 100%, I want to put all of my other content (everything that will go in the content div) beneath it. Here is my current code:

98.214.131.200/index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="http://tri-peoria.org">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/forum">Forum</a></li>
    <li><a href="/join">Join</a></li>
    <li><a href="/members">Members</a></li>
    <li><a href="/events">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="/training">Training</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/tripeoria/">Facebook</a></li>
    <ab><a href="/about">Peoria Triathlon Club</a></ab>
</ul>
<ul id="quote">
<p>"random quote"</p>
</ul>
<div id="bg"><img src="bg.jpg" width="100%" alt=""</img></div>
<div id="content">
<p>content</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

98.214.131.200/style.css

```
body {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #C1C1C1;
    font-family: Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}
#bg {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    }
#content {
    position:relative;
    color: #FFF;
    }
#nav {
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li {
    float: left; }
#nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #c00;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff; }
#nav ab {
    float: right; }
#nav ab a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #c00;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
#nav ab a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff; }
#quote{
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
}
#quote p {
    color: #000;
    width: 350px;
}
```

You can visit http:// 98.214.131.200 to see my current code.

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. Put the image first.

Comment: Do you need to add a background to div ?

Comment: Side note:  Your image tag is incorrect.  It should be `<img src="bg.jpg" width="100%" alt="" />`

Comment: divs should flow like that naturally. remove all the css properties form your #bg and #content declerations and then adjust from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the `<p>` out of the `<ul>`, and place it (along with the `#content` `<p>`) inside of `#bg`. Then revisit your positioning declarations...

Absolute positioned elements depend on a parent container with Relative positioning. Thus, `#bg` should be `position:relative` while `#quote` `position:absolute`. By using `#bg` as the parent for both the quote and the content - you keep everything relative to that one element you're trying to focus on.

Built a fiddle (using your IP address for the images).
http://jsfiddle.net/bqXc6/

Here's the gist tho:

```
#bg { position:relative; width:100%; }
#quote {
    position:absolute;
    color: #000;
    top: 20px;
    width: 350px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
#content { color:#FFF; margin-left:20px; }
```

Please note: In the fiddle, I cleaned up your code for your 'float:left' nav elements using overflow hidden on their parent (just to push open the height/width) so it's background-color was visible.​

Answer (score 0):

You should embed your #nav and #quote elements into a `div` or `header` tag and position it absolutely. Then you can position you image container relatively, which will push down subsequent content.

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul id="nav"></ul>
    <ul id="quote></ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#header{
    position: absolute;
}
#bg{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: That makes the content's position behave properly but it leaves a big black bar across the top, look at http:// 98.214.131.200 to see

Comment: Then you should position #nav and #quote absolutely, and not -1 if our answers don't work oob. You DO need position: relative for your image to push the lower content down.

Answer (score 0):

To put background image, use following css property

background-image:url('yourimage.jpg');

Comment: A background image does not size properly for all window widths

Comment: It does and even better than an img tag - are you familiar with the `background-size` property?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the display: block css property to make it it display on its own line. Just add that property to #bg in your css stylesheet.

Comment: `div`s are block-level elements - no need to define that characteristic. The problem the OP is having is/was caused by altering the document flow through the use of positioning. I didn't down vote you (fyi).